# Using sum + countifs to count items across many (26 to be exact) tabs/sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I have a scheduling program where I'm tallying up certain shifts across 26 pay periods, each with it's own tab or sheet. My current example below is adding up two types of evening shifts...P & P8, in a particular row (C4:P4) across 26 tabs/sheets, but it's pretty unwieldy. Is there a better way to do this?

```
=sum(countif({
'PP1'!C4:P4,
'PP2'!C4:P4,
'PP3'!C4:P4,
'PP4'!C4:P4,
'PP5'!C4:P4,
'PP6'!C4:P4,
'PP7'!C4:P4,
'PP8'!C4:P4,
'PP9'!C4:P4,
'PP10'!C4:P4,
'PP11'!C4:P4,
'PP12'!C4:P4,
'PP13'!C4:P4,
'PP14'!C4:P4,
'PP15'!C4:P4,
'PP16'!C4:P4,
'PP17'!C4:P4,
'PP18'!C4:P4,
'PP19'!C4:P4,
'PP20'!C4:P4,
'PP21'!C4:P4,
'PP22'!C4:P4,
'PP23'!C4:P4,
'PP24'!C4:P4,
'PP25'!C4:P4,
'PP26'!C4:P4
},"P"),countif({
'PP1'!C4:P4,
'PP2'!C4:P4,
'PP3'!C4:P4,
'PP4'!C4:P4,
'PP5'!C4:P4,
'PP6'!C4:P4,
'PP7'!C4:P4,
'PP8'!C4:P4,
'PP9'!C4:P4,
'PP10'!C4:P4,
'PP11'!C4:P4,
'PP12'!C4:P4,
'PP13'!C4:P4,
'PP14'!C4:P4,
'PP15'!C4:P4,
'PP16'!C4:P4,
'PP17'!C4:P4,
'PP18'!C4:P4,
'PP19'!C4:P4,
'PP20'!C4:P4,
'PP21'!C4:P4,
'PP22'!C4:P4,
'PP23'!C4:P4,
'PP24'!C4:P4,
'PP25'!C4:P4,
'PP26'!C4:P4
},"P8"))
```

Comment: Can you share the sheet to test it?

Comment: Yes. Here it is. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eb2QE_aWaCsGaoEZjmij7JhmfWJT1oEIRjSEj0kRC1o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm working from the Stats sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(INDEX(N(REGEXMATCH({
 'PP1'!C4:P4,
 'PP2'!C4:P4,
 'PP3'!C4:P4,
 'PP4'!C4:P4,
 'PP5'!C4:P4,
 'PP6'!C4:P4,
 'PP7'!C4:P4,
 'PP8'!C4:P4,
 'PP9'!C4:P4,
 'PP10'!C4:P4,
 'PP11'!C4:P4,
 'PP12'!C4:P4,
 'PP13'!C4:P4,
 'PP14'!C4:P4,
 'PP15'!C4:P4,
 'PP16'!C4:P4,
 'PP17'!C4:P4,
 'PP18'!C4:P4,
 'PP19'!C4:P4,
 'PP20'!C4:P4,
 'PP21'!C4:P4,
 'PP22'!C4:P4,
 'PP23'!C4:P4,
 'PP24'!C4:P4,
 'PP25'!C4:P4,
 'PP26'!C4:P4}, "^P8$|^P$"))))
```

Comment: Thanks player0, but that doesn't work.  I'm confused by the 'N' as the first input of INDEX.

Comment: you may wanna use `"^P8$|^P$"` instead of `"P8|P"`. in your sheet that will result in `18` instead of `39` - answer updated

Comment: Still not working.  I'm working on staging the data on another sheet to make for an easier formula.  I'll post when I figure that out.

Comment: see the red cell: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f6SgyeGUgyUUztqrxWjRqt4OQ5CMhJfDSh8Hx90ftj8/edit#gid=1741779369